# Langchain MRKL Agent not giving useful Final Answer

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

Here is the code I'm using for initializing a Zero Shot ReAct Agent with some tools for fetching relevant documents from a vector database:

```
chat_model = ChatOpenAI(
            model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            temperature="0",
            openai_api_key=openai_api_key,
            streaming=True,
            # verbose=True)

llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=chat_model, prompt=prompt)

agent = ZeroShotAgent(llm_chain=llm_chain, tools=tools, verbose=True, handle_parsing_errors=True)
agent_chain = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
    agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True, memory=memory
)
```

However when I query for a response.

```
query = "Can you explain a use case example of chain of thought prompting in detail?"
res = agent_chain(query)
```

This is the response I get back:

```
> Entering new  chain...
Thought: The question is asking for a detailed explanation of a use example of chain-of-thought prompting.
Action: Lookup from database
Action Input: "use example of chain-of-thought prompting"
Observation: Sure! Here's an example of chain-of-thought prompting:

Let's say we have a language model that is trained to solve math word problems. We want to use chain-of-thought prompting to improve its reasoning abilities.

The prompt consists of triples: input, chain of thought, output. For example:

Input: "John has 5 apples."
Chain of Thought: "If John gives 2 apples to Mary, how many apples does John have left?"
Output: "John has 3 apples left."

In this example, the chain of thought is a series of intermediate reasoning steps that lead to the final output. It helps the language model understand the problem and perform the necessary calculations.
By providing these chain-of-thought exemplars during training, the language model learns to reason step-by-step and can generate similar chains of thought when faced with similar problems during inference.
This approach of chain-of-thought prompting has been shown to improve the performance of language models on various reasoning tasks, including arithmetic, commonsense, and symbolic reasoning. It allows the models to decompose complex problems into manageable steps and allocate additional computation when needed.
Overall, chain-of-thought prompting enhances the reasoning abilities of large language models and helps them achieve state-of-the-art performance on challenging tasks.

Thought: I have provided a detailed explanation and example of chain-of-thought prompting.

Final Answer: Chain-of-thought prompting is a method used to improve the reasoning abilities of large language models by providing demonstrations of chain-of-thought reasoning as exemplars in prompting. It involves breaking down multi-step problems into manageable intermediate steps, leading to more effective reasoning and problem-solving. An example of chain-of-thought prompting is providing a language model with a math word problem prompt consisting of an input, chain of thought, and output. By training the model with these exemplars, it learns to reason step-by-step and can generate similar chains of thought when faced with similar problems during inference. This approach has been shown to enhance the performance of language models on various reasoning tasks.

> Finished chain.
```

As you can observe, The model has a very thorough and exact answer which I need in it's observation part. However in the consequent thought, the model thinks it is done providing a detailed explanation and example to the human. So the final answer is just some basic information, not really answering the question in necessary detail.

I feel like somewhere in the intermediate steps, the agent thinks it has already answered to the human, and hence just does not bother to give the full answer as the final answer.

Is it an issue with chat based models? Should I be playing around with prompt template?

Can someone please help me figure out, how can I make the model output it's observation as the final answer. Or to stop making the model assume it has already answered the question to the human.

Here is a prompt template that I tried using:

```
prefix = """You are a Professional Teacher Chatbot.
            Have a conversation with a human, who is your student, over an academic topic from a     database of documents,
            answering the questions as best, academically and elaborately as you can.
            Your goal is to provide as much detail as you can possibly gather
            from the database of documents by thoroughly going through it.
            If you get a proper exact answer from the
            document, do not try to summarise your observations and thoughts, give your final answer as the
            whole of observations and thoughts you found, exactly as it is.
            Be professional and explain everything you found.

            You have access to the following tools: 

""""
```

However it still didn't result in the agent giving a final detailed response. It does think in detail when it is observing, but it cuts it down in the final answer as already mentioned.